# Can parallel processing be achieved?

Tags: parallel-processing, embedded, stm32

Can an MCU really do parallel processing?

Let's just say that I wana countdown, send data through another interface, and do one more work such as Light up an LED all at the sametime.

Is that even possible?

Comment: While the question may be legitimate your example use case is hardly a typical or useful example of parallel processing - they are tasks that would not really benefit from parallel processing.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, my question was just based on the possibility of doing any parallel process. And so, I am interested in the question because by knowing the answer it would lead me to think for other more processes that I can do at the same time. It might not be useful, but like what I said, it's just an example.

Comment: I take your point, but that is not generally what parallel processing is useful for - you can do that with a simple multi-tasking scheduler (see [RTOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system)).  Specifically since it is tagged STM32, that is exactly what you need.

Comment: Not with the CPU core, though it is possible you may be able to get some combinations of things to happen concurrently using the on-chip hardware peripheral engines.  However, where these need to obtain data their access to internal busses may be serialized (forced to get in line) by the bus arbitration logic.  To take your example, you might do the countdown with a hardware timer, send the data with a serial interface engine backed by DMA, and light the LED from another timer channel.  To an extent these will be parallel, though (re)configuring them will not be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A processor with multiple execution units or cores can perform parallel processing.  Most microcontrollers do not have multiple execution units.

Some architectures support SIMD (Single Instruction/Multiple Data) instructions that can generate multiple results from a single instruction - this is a low level form of parallel processing, similarly DSPs (Digital Signal Processors) and microcontrollers with DSP instructions support dual or multiple MAC (multiply/accumulate) units that are also a form of parallel processing.  Both SIMD and MAC are used primarily for number crunching and signal processing applications.  High end DSPs often support other instruction level parallel execution capabilities.

Another low-level architecture feature that allows parallel execution is [pipeline execution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28computing%29).  This allows instructions that may take multiple cycles to run to generate one result per cycle by running different stages of the same operation simultaneously.

Most microcontrollers can support a multi-tasking or multi-threading scheduler that can give the impression of concurrent execution by scheduling execution time to each task according to the scheduling algorithm used.  While this is not parallel processing and in fact adds an overhead rather than accelerates processing, it is useful in other ways such as functional partitioning of the code and, in the case of a *real-time priority based preemptive* scheduler, achieving real-time response to events.  For the example use case you give in your question, this form of scheduling is entirely appropriate and adequate. See [Real-time Operating System (RTOS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system)

Microcontroller architectures that do support true parallel processing include [XMOS](http://www.xmos.com/), [PicoChip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PicoChip), and the [Cell processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_%28microprocessor%29).  Historically the [Transputer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transputer) pioneered parallel processing in microprocessors.

A way of achieving a high level of parallelism at a low level where individual operations of the same process can occur simultaneously (when one does not depend of the result of the other, or a [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28computing%29) is used) is to implement a process on an FPGA - essentially to implement the processing in hardware rather than software, but the languages used to program FPGAs share similarities with software languages.

Answer (score 0):

A company named [Parallax](http://www.parallaxsemiconductor.com/) makes an 8 core MCU called Propeller that does parallel processing. Their programming language "Spin" is interesting, object oriented, scriptish, but also has inline assembly.